# How can I install npm for Opsworks Rails application layer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu-12.04, npm, aws-opsworks

On Ubuntu 12.04, if you install nodejs through the regular sources

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

You'll get an older version of nodejs (0.6) that does not contain npm. You can manually [install the upstream version](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nodejs/node-js-npm-install-ubuntu/) and then you will have npm.

Similarily, adding nodejs to OS packages on the Rails applicaiton Layer gives me the older version of node. How can I can install a nodejs with npm for a Rails application layer on OpsWorks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpsWorks nodejs cookbook](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.4/opsworks_nodejs). Make sure you add opsworks_cookbook to Custom Recipes -> Setup, on your Rails application layer. This forces your instance to install the nodejs cookbook on startup, like it would by default if this was a nodejs application layer. You don't need to add nodejs to your OS packages, since it is installed at the setup part of the lifecycle.

Then, in your stack's custom json, set the desired nodejs version :

```
{
  "opsworks_nodejs": {
    "version": "0.10.25"
  },
}
```